# Got water in oil while flushing radiator. What should I do now?

Tags: oil, coolant

I was flushing my radiator and I got water in my oil. What do I need to do?

Comment: It would really help if you explained a bit more. How did you get the water into your oil? Any idea how much water?

Comment: As @dlu stated, please. And remember, we aren't here to judge, only to help.

Answer (score 4):

The conservative thing would be to do an oil change.

But if it is a relatively small amount of water, I don't think I'd worry too much about it. Just drive the car soon so that the engine gets completely up to operating temperature and the water evaporates.

Where I would be concerned is if there was a chance that enough water got in so that the oil pump pickup could be sitting in a pool of water under the oil.

If you're concerned that a lot of water may have gone into the engine – for example if you mistook the oil fill for the radiator cap (I've done worse) – you can get a rough idea by looking at the dip stick. Oil will float on top of the water and if your oil is suddenly much higher then you know you've got a lot of water in there. Then I would change it for sure.

Comment: I was flushing the radiator and grab the wrong hose and now my oil milky

Comment: @Michaeldavis, any idea how much water and where it went in?

Comment: Not a whole lot.. But now oil looks milky. Should I just change the oil and be done with it or?????

Comment: Personally, I would probably use it as an occasion to do an oil change – have you run the engine? I'm curious about the milky part, I wouldn't expect that to happen unless the engine was run, but I don't have all that much experience with water in the oil.

Comment: Yes.  Change the oil and be done with it.  You may want to change it a second time if it's milky.  Change it, run it a bit, change it again.   Cheers!  Welcome to the site!

Comment: Run it long enough to get good and hot so that the water will have plenty of time to evaporate.